# ClassNotFoundException on custom Application class (not in APK/dex files?)

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, classnotfoundexception

I'm at a loss on this...  I have an app that was previously compiling and working, that now cannot find its own custom Application class.  I looked in the APK at each dex file and don't see it anywhere.  I rarely update the app code anymore, so it's not like a recent code / gradle change should have caused this.  Below is the stacktrace from logcat:

```
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime: Process: <app_package_name>, PID: 19148
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application <app_package_name>.<MyCustomApplicationClass>: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "<app_package_name>.<MyCustomApplicationClass>" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/<app_package_name>-...==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/<app_package_name>-...==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:948)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5759)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6535)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "<app_package_name>.<MyCustomApplicationClass>" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/<app_package_name>-...==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/<app_package_name>-...==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1086)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:942)
07-13 23:35:47.273 19148 19148 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
07-13 23:35:47.297  1630  2640 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity <app_package_name>/<core_module_package>.HomeActivity
07-13 23:35:47.481  1630  1715 W AppOps  : Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
07-13 23:35:47.794  1630  1657 W Looper  : Dispatch took 373ms on android.ui, h=Handler (android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler) {3a74f28} cb=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver@94b1441 msg=0
07-13 23:35:47.803  1630  1656 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{6da3ef1 u0 <app_package_name>/<core_module_package>.HomeActivity t18 f}
07-13 23:35:48.134  1630  1657 W Looper  : Dispatch took 181ms on android.ui, h=Handler (com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$UiHandler) {43c2d01} cb=null msg=30
07-13 23:35:48.414  2544 19186 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1173f3f does not exist
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:5609)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:5602)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:1644)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:209)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3488)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:6306)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3882)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
07-13 23:35:48.446  1630  1715 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
07-13 23:35:48.718  1630  1777 E TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
07-13 23:35:53.485  2544 19186 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
07-13 23:35:58.452  1630  1656 W ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{6da3ef1 u0 <app_package_name>/<core_module_package>.HomeActivity t18 f}
```

The app is arranged as a few gradle modules.  There's one core module with most of the app code.  Then there's `free` and `pro` modules that customize what features the user sees.  Each has its own custom `Application` class that extends a custom `Application` class in the core module.  After the crash, I pulled up the APK analyzer in Android Studio (latest 3.5 beta at the moment) and saw no signs of the custom `Application` class in any of the dex files.

I've tried adding a couple of Proguard lines to `-keep` everything in the package.  I've also tried `-dontobfuscate`.

Yes, the custom `Application` classes are listed in the AndroidManifest.xml of each module, are correctly spelled, etc.  I've tried both absolute and relative paths to the class with the same result.  I tried disabling R8 and that didn't help either.

The app is set for API levels 23 to 28, uses AndroidX, etc.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

EDIT:

Here's the relevant bits of Manifest:

This is the relevant piece the "pro" module's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="<package>">

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:name=".<CustomName>Application"
        tools:replace="android:name">
```

And this is the relevant piece the core module's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="<base_package>">

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="<base_package>.<CustomBase>Application"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:targetSandboxVersion="1">
```

The custom Application class in the core module extends `MultiDexApplication`.

Comment: Can you post your code please? Manifest and activity where you are getting the crash?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai I posted the relevant bits of the Manifests.  I don't see where the Activity is relevant b/c (1) it is unchanged from when it compiled & ran fine and (2) the Application class is NOT in the APK, which sounds more like a proguard / compile issue, not a runtime issue.

Comment: it's relevant because you have an error: `WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1173f3f does not exist`. So I would like to see how/what views you are inflating.